# `asyncio.wait` confusion when passed a coroutine

Tags: python, async-await, task, python-asyncio, coroutine

[asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) says:

> Passing coroutines objects to wait() directly is deprecated as it leads to confusing behavior.

and gives this as the confusing behavior:

> `wait()` schedules coroutines as Tasks automatically and later returns those implicitly created Task objects in (done, pending) sets. Therefore the following code won’t work as expected: *[I modified the code snippet below so that it runs]*
>
> ```
> async def foo():
>     return 42
>
> async def main():
>     coro = foo()
>     done, pending = await asyncio.wait({coro})
>
>     if coro in done:
>         # This branch will never be run!
>         print('yay!')
>
> asyncio.run(main())
> ```

I just started learning about `asyncio`, so I don't fully understand. Can someone explain?

Comment: `asyncio.wait` is not necessarily called in an `await` statement, and this is not part of the confusion that is meant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code that is given in the documentation is:

```
coro = foo()
done, pending = await asyncio.wait({coro})

if coro in done:
    # This branch will never be run!
```

The reason that this code gives unexpected results is as follows:

- `coro` is a coroutine object.
- When it is passed to `asyncio.wait`, it automatically creates a `Task` object from it (which is different from the coroutine object), like `coro_task = create_task(coro)` (see [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task)).
- When `asyncio.wait` is done, it returns two sets:

  - a set of tasks that are already done
  - a set of tasks that are not done yet

So in this case, it will return one set that contains `coro_task` and one set that is empty.

Note that the original coroutine object `coro` (which is different from `coro_task`) is *not contained in any of the sets*, so checking if it is in the "done" set, is pointless - it will never be contained, even if the corresponding task, `coro_task` is already done.

The fix is to create the `Task` object for `coro` *outside* of `asyncio.wait`, which will allow to test if that *same* object is contained in one or the other of the returned sets, in order to determine if the task is done.

In Python versions starting from 3.8 you will get a deprecation warning if you pass a coroutine to `asyncio.wait`, and since version 3.11 it will be an error, i.e. you are forced to use the "fixed" code.