# The explicit passing of coroutine objects to asyncio.wait() is deprecated

Tags: python, python-asyncio

From this github link: https://github.com/pyxll/pyxll-examples/blob/master/bitmex/bitmex.py

When I run this code, I get the message saying the explicit passing of coroutine objects to asyncio.wait() is deprecated. I've pinpointed this to line 71: `await asyncio.wait(tasks)`, but can't figure out how to resolve the issue.

Code below for reference:

```
from pyxll import xl_func, RTD, get_event_loop
import websockets
import asyncio
import json


class BitMex:
    """Class to manage subscriptions to instrument prices."""

    URI = "wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime"

    def __init__(self, loop=None):
        self.__websocket = None
        self.__running = False
        self.__running_task = None
        self.__subscriptions = {}
        self.__data = {}
        self.__lock = asyncio.Lock(loop=loop)

    async def __connect(self):
        # Connect to the websocket API and start the __run coroutine
        self.__running = True
        self.__websocket = await websockets.connect(self.URI)
        self.__connecting_task = None
        self.__running_task = asyncio.create_task(self.__run())

    async def __disconnect(self):
        # Close the websocket and wait for __run to complete
        self.__running = False
        await self.__websocket.close()
        self.__websocket = None
        await self.__running_task

    async def __run(self):
        # Read from the websocket until disconnected
        while self.__running:
            msg = await self.__websocket.recv()
            await self.__process_message(json.loads(msg))

    async def __process_message(self, msg):
        if msg.get("table", None) == "instrument":
            # Extract the data from the message, update our data dictionary and notify subscribers
            for data in msg.get("data", []):
                symbol = data["symbol"]
                timestamp = data["symbol"]

                # Update the latest values in our data dictionary and notify any subscribers
                tasks = []
                subscribers = self.__subscriptions.get(symbol, {})
                latest = self.__data.setdefault(symbol, {})
                for field, value in data.items():
                    latest[field] = (value, timestamp)

                    # Notify the subscribers with the updated field
                    for subscriber in subscribers.get(field, []):
                        tasks.append(subscriber(symbol, field, value, timestamp))

                # await all the tasks from the subscribers
                if tasks:
                    await asyncio.wait(tasks)

    async def subscribe(self, symbol, field, callback):
        """Subscribe to updates for a specific symbol and field.

        The callback will be called as 'await callback(symbol, field, value, timestamp)'
        whenever an update is received.
        """
        async with self.__lock:
            # Connect the websocket if necessary
            if self.__websocket is None:
                await self.__connect()

            # Send the subscribe message if we're not already subscribed
            if symbol not in self.__subscriptions:
                msg = {"op": "subscribe", "args": [f"instrument:{symbol}"]}
                await self.__websocket.send(json.dumps(msg))

            # Add the subscriber to the dict of subscriptions
            self.__subscriptions.setdefault(symbol, {}).setdefault(field, []).append(callback)

            # Call the callback with the latest data
            data = self.__data.get(symbol, {})
            if field in data:
                (value, timestamp) = data[field]
                await callback(symbol, field, value, timestamp)

    async def unsubscribe(self, symbol, field, callback):
        async with self.__lock:
            # Remove the subscriber from the list of subscriptions
            self.__subscriptions[symbol][field].remove(callback)
            if not self.__subscriptions[symbol][field]:
                del self.__subscriptions[symbol][field]

            # Unsubscribe if we no longer have any subscriptions for this instrument
            if not self.__subscriptions[symbol]:
                msg = {"op": "unsubscribe", "args": [f"instrument:{symbol}"]}
                await self.__websocket.send(json.dumps(msg))
                del self.__subscriptions[symbol]
                self.__data.pop(symbol, None)

            # Disconnect if we no longer have any subscriptions
            if not self.__subscriptions:
                async with self.__lock:
                    await self.__disconnect()


class BitMexRTD(RTD):
    """RTD class for subscribing to BitMEX prices using the
    BitMex class above.
    """

    # Use a single BitMex object for all RTD functions
    _bitmex = BitMex(get_event_loop())

    def __init__(self, symbol, field):
        super().__init__(value="Waiting...")
        self.__symbol = symbol
        self.__field = field

    async def connect(self):
        # Subscribe to BitMix updates when Excel connects to the RTD object
        await self._bitmex.subscribe(self.__symbol, self.__field, self.__update)

    async def disconnect(self):
        # Unsubscribe to BitMix updates when Excel disconnects from the RTD object
        await self._bitmex.unsubscribe(self.__symbol, self.__field, self.__update)

    async def __update(self, symbol, field, value, timestamp):
        # Update the value in Excel
        self.value = value


@xl_func("string symbol, string field: rtd", recalc_on_open=True)
def bitmex_rtd(symbol, field="lastPrice"):
    """Subscribe to BitMEX prices for a given symbol."""
    return BitMexRTD(symbol, field)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    async def main():
        # This is the callback that will be called whenever there's an update
        async def callback(symbol, field, value, timestamp):
            print((symbol, field, value, timestamp))

        bm = BitMex()

        await bm.subscribe("XBTUSD", "lastPrice", callback)

        await asyncio.sleep(60)

        await bm.unsubscribe("XBTUSD", "lastPrice", callback)

        print("DONE!")

    # Run the 'main' function in an asyncio event loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: What did you find in the documentation of the `asyncio.wait` function about this?

Comment: That's just a warning.  It won't affect the script execution.

Comment: It will be depreciated October this year though.

Comment: I tried to change it based on these 2 links, but couldn't quite get it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889075/asyncio-wait-confusion-when-passed-a-coroutine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029772/alternative-to-asyncio-wait

Comment: Passing coroutines to `wait` was deprecated in Python 3.8. As of Python 3.11 (released this *past* October), passing coroutines to `wait` is forbidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass the `tasks` list to `asyncio.wait()`.  [The documentation for `asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) states *"Run Future and Task instances in the aws iterable concurrently and block until the condition specified by return_when."*. The type returned by an `async def ...(...)`-like defined function is a coroutine(`type(async_function)==types.coroutine#true`). Since this is neither a Future nor a Task, the warning is outputted. To fix it, just leave asyncio.wait() and the tasks list inside of `__process_message` out entirely:

```
    async def __process_message(self, msg):
    if msg.get("table", None) == "instrument":
        # Extract the data from the message, update our data dictionary and notify subscribers
        for data in msg.get("data", []):
            symbol = data["symbol"]
            timestamp = data["symbol"]

            # Update the latest values in our data dictionary and notify any subscribers
            subscribers = self.__subscriptions.get(symbol, {})
            latest = self.__data.setdefault(symbol, {})
            for field, value in data.items():
                latest[field] = (value, timestamp)

                # Notify the subscribers with the updated field
                for subscriber in subscribers.get(field, []):
                    await subscriber(symbol, field, value, timestamp)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works and now I see how this aligns with the other suggestions I was reading about. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

`tasks` shouldn't be a list of `Coroutine`s but a list of `Task`s instead.
You can use `asyncio.create_task(coroutine)` to get the job done.

```py
# you should change
tasks.append(subscriber(symbol, field, value, timestamp))

# into
task = asyncio.create_task(subscriber(symbol, field, value, timestamp))
tasks.append(task)
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @tom_139 and there few other way to achieve various concurrent outcomes, eg:

```py
async do_thing(o: int) -> int:
    """ do something with s
    """
    await asyncio.wait(0.001)
    return o*o

result = sum([await do_thing(stuff) for stuff in lots_of_stuff])

# if you don't care about the result then:
_ = [await do_thing(stuff) for stuff in lots_of_stuff]


# or in similar ways to the comment above, here is cut & paste from some production code.

    logger.info("Waiting for %s commands to execute", batch_size)
    tasks = [ioloop.create_task(perform_command(api)) for _ in range(batch_size)]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here from Google this *is* a warning that you need to fix, because the full warning is:

> DeprecationWarning: The explicit passing of coroutine objects to asyncio.wait() is deprecated since Python 3.8, ***and scheduled for removal in Python 3.11.***

The `asyncio.wait()` documentation obviously says nothing about this or what you're supposed to do instead, but as far as I can figure out you replace `asyncio.wait([a, b])` with `asyncio.gather(a, b)`.

Comment: `wait` and `gather` have different purposes.  A more suitable solution might be along the lines of `asyncio.wait([asyncio.create_task(a), asyncio.create_task(b)])` if `wait` is truly needed—although I myself am struggling right now with finding a way to turn an `Awaitable` (like the result of an `anext()` call) into a `Task`.

Comment: Okay, worked it out: basically had to wrap the `anext` call inside something like `async def a_coroutine(awaitable): return await anext(awaitable)`, which itself is a coroutine and can be wrapped within `create_task`.

Comment: `wait` and `gather` have the same purpose as far as I can tell. Read the docs of `gather`. It automatically makes tasks.

Comment: I promise you, I've read the docs more times than I'd like to admit.  `gather` is your go-to if you need to wait until **all** tasks complete (or one fails).  If you need to be able to intercept when **some** tasks complete but not others, you need `wait`.

Comment: Ah right, yeah in this case I wanted all of them.

Comment: I use `asyncio.wait(my_tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED`, such functionality isn't available with `asyncio.gather()`.